# Add a label/text to BIRT report parameters window

Tags: parameters, label, report, birt

In BIRT, the report parameters window that pops up for user input only has 4 options for input type: text box, combo box, list box and radio button. I need to add a simple label with some extra text to this window, just text with no input associated with it, like where it automatically says "Parameters marked with * are required." (see attached image). Anyone know how I can go about this?

[image]

Comment: There are options for building a custom parameter window. I have seen them mentioned but have not built one, I believe you can accomplish your goal that way.

Comment: If I had more time I would certainly look into it, but your solution may be of help someone else who views this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to make use of a parameter group for this. Create an empty parameter group and set in "Display name" field your label.

If you set a specific prefix to this group, you can test the prefix in *ParameterGroupFragment.jsp* and then customize styling for your labels (set a specific icon, a css class etc.).

Comment: Yeah its a quick fix but that'll to do me for now. I have to work with a fairly old version of BIRT, perhaps what I am asking is possible in a newer version. Thanks